# Within quotes, do I write Saint or St.?

Tags: abbreviations, quotes

Specifically, I'm writing a biography for a man who lived in St. Maries, Idaho. When I'm quoting him (therefore the spoken language) should I spell out saint, or is it a common enough abbreviation, like Dr., to leave abbreviated?
"I grew up in Saint Maries." OR "I grew up in St. Maries." ??

Comment: St. is common enough to be left like that though writing ID for Idaho would be probably be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Henry, That's kind of my thinking but looking for reinforcement. :)

Comment: Punctuation is nearly always a matter of *style*, and as a result a definitive answer is rarely possible; for that reason, the vast majority of EL&U questions about punctuation end up being closed as primarily opinion-based. ...

Comment: FWIW: if you expect your biography to be published, check the publisher's **style guide** (and if they're a good publisher, they'll have an editor whose job is to find and resolve these very issues!). If you're self-publishing, choose your own style guide from [the list on this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide); for US writers, two to consider are the Chicago Manual and the MLA Handbook, while BritE writers might prefer Fowler's or the Oxford or Cambridge Guides. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I basically know the rules, but occasionally it's open for opinion. I've made the choice to go with St. Maries. However, as you wrote--it ultimately is up to the publishing company's editor.